# Adding a trailing Stop loss to an expert advisor using MQL5

Tags: algorithmic-trading, expert-system, mql5, forex, metatrader5

Hi I'm new to MQL5 and I wanted to add a trailing stop loss to my expert advisor but some reason it does not add. Here is the code:

```
 if(PositionSelect(_Symbol) && UseTrailingStop == true)
  {
   double TrailingStop = (atr[1] * 3) + close[1];
   Trail.TrailingStop(_Symbol,TrailingStop,0,0);
  }
```

Please note that close[1] is for the close price of the previous bar and atr[1] is for the value of the average true range. What am i doing wrong?????

Comment: I think the easier solution will be extend the CTrailing and do the calculation in the two methods that you will overwrite there (CheckTrailingStopLong and CheckTrailingStopShort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go: hope this is helpful.

```
//--- trailing position  
   for(i=0;i<PositionsTotal();i++)
     {
      if(Symbol()==PositionGetSymbol(i))
        {
         if(PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE)==POSITION_TYPE_BUY)
           {
            sl=MathMax(PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN)+Spread*_Point,Bid-SL*_Point);

            if(sl>PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL) && (Bid-StopLevel*_Point-Spread*_Point)>PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN))
              {
               request.action = TRADE_ACTION_SLTP;
               request.symbol = _Symbol;
               request.sl = NormalizeDouble(sl,_Digits);
               request.tp = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP);
               OrderSend(request,result);
               if(result.retcode==10009 || result.retcode==10008) // request executed
                  Print("Moving Stop Loss of Buy position #",request.order);
               else
                 {
                  Print(ResultRetcodeDescription(result.retcode));
                  return;
                 }
               return;
              }
           }

         if(PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE)==POSITION_TYPE_SELL)
           {
            sl=MathMin(PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN)-Spread*_Point,Ask+SL*_Point);

            if(sl<PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL) && (PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN)-StopLevel*_Point-Spread*_Point)>Ask)
              {
               request.action = TRADE_ACTION_SLTP;
               request.symbol = _Symbol;
               request.sl = NormalizeDouble(sl,_Digits);
               request.tp = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP);
               OrderSend(request,result);
               if(result.retcode==10009 || result.retcode==10008) // request executed
                  Print("Moving Stop Loss of Sell position #",request.order);
               else
                 {
                  Print(ResultRetcodeDescription(result.retcode));
                  return;
                 }
               return;
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.